# Show that function is strictly monotone increasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I want to show that $$ f(x)=\dfrac{x-\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)} $$ is strictly increasing in $(0,2 \pi) $. Unforunately, this is not that easy for me , as the derivative is not very manageable and trigonometric identities appear to be not very helpful, too.$$$$

Are there any further ways to do this?

Comment: Note that the denominator is actually the derivative of the numerator.

Comment: Yes. How does it help?

Comment: Well, I do not know how this might help too.

Comment: It is trivial in $(\pi,2\pi)$, since the numerator increases and the denominator decreases.

Comment: In which standard you are @Lipschitz ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $f(x)=\dfrac{x-\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$

```
EDIT: I am wrong in the formula  for the last version and I correct here,sorry for it.
```

$f'(x)=\dfrac{(x-\sin x)(-\sin x)}{(1-\cos x)^2}+\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos x}=\dfrac{\sin^2x-x\sin x+1-2\cos x+\cos^2 x}{(1-\cos x)^2}=\dfrac{2(1-\cos x)-x\sin x}{(1-\cos x)^2}=\dfrac{2\cdot 2\sin^2 \dfrac{x}{2}-2x\sin\dfrac{x}{2}\cos{x}{2}}{(1-\cos x)^2}=\dfrac{2\cdot sin \dfrac{x}{2}}{(1-\cos x)^2}\cdot (2\sin\dfrac{x}{2}-x\cos x \dfrac{x}{2}) $

$\dfrac{2\cdot \sin \dfrac{x}{2}}{(1-\cos x)^2}>0 $  when  $0<x<2\pi$,

so we only check  $(2\sin\dfrac{x}{2}-x\cos x \dfrac{x}{2}) $.

When $0< x < \pi, \tan\dfrac{x}{2}>\dfrac{x}{2},$ we have $ 2\sin\dfrac{x}{2}>x\cos x \dfrac{x}{2}$, ie. $2\sin\dfrac{x}{2}-x\cos x \dfrac{x}{2}>0$.

When $\pi \leq x < 2\pi$, $\cos\dfrac{x}{2} \leq 0, -x \cos\dfrac{x}{2} \ge 0,$ and $2\sin\dfrac{x}{2}>0$, ie. $2\sin\dfrac{x}{2}-x\cos x \dfrac{x}{2}>0$

so $f'(x)>0$  when $0<x<2\pi$, QED

Comment: well done, thank you!

Comment: But $$\frac{x_2-\sin(x_2)}{1-\cos(x_2)}-\frac{x_1-\sin(x_1)}{1-\cos(x_1)} \not= \frac{x_2-x_1+\sin(x_2)\cos(x_1)-\cos(x_2)\sin(x_1)}{(1-\cos(x_2))(1-\cos(x_1))}$$

Comment: It should be \begin{align} \frac{x_2-\sin(x_2)}{1-\cos(x_2)}-\dfrac{x_1-\sin(x_1)}{1-\cos(x_1)} \\ =\frac{x_2-x_1-x_2\cos(x_1)+x_1\cos(x_2)-\sin(x_2)+\sin(x_1)+\sin(x_2)\cos(x_1)-\cos(x_2)\sin(x_1)}{(1-\cos(x_2))(1-\cos(x_1))} \end{align}

Comment: @IvanLoh: you are right , i made a mistake and correct now. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As ᴊᴀsᴏɴ said, you can

> Note that the denominator is actually the derivative of the numerator.

Which can be written as $f(x)=\frac{u}{u'}$ and we know that $\frac{d \ln(u)}{dx}=\frac{u'}{u}$ which represents the slope of the $\ln$ function on the interval mapped by $u(x)$ where $x\in]0,2\pi[$

Now think about it, the slope of the $ln$ function is strictly decreasing, so you can see your function as the inverse of this slope and thus strictly increasing.

Comment: Thanks Siminore, I was just editing it myself, you were faster :)

Comment: By the way, also note that this holds because $u$ is strictly increasing on $]0,2\pi[$

Comment: Nope.You can't say that. It's the slope of $ln u$ that decreases , you can't say it to  be same as $lnx$. We don't know about what is behavior of $ln u$ over $]0,2\pi[$.

Comment: Well, all we know from the decreasing ln-function is, that $\frac{d ln(u)}{dx}=\frac{u'}{u} <0 $. but this is obvious. one woud need something about the second derivative. the statement that ln is strictly decreasing just tells us, that $\frac{u'}{u}$ is always negative for $ x \in (0,2\pi)$ but not that it is strictly decreasing.

Comment: No, $ln$ is not strictly decreasing, it's derivative is. And that's exactly what I said, when I say the slope is decreasing I'm indirectly talking about the sign of the second derivative.
About what exploringnet said, well I'm pretty sure you can, because since $u$ is strictly increasing and continuous on $]0,2\pi[$, it maps to a subinterval of $]0,+\infty[$ where the slope of the $ln$ function is strictly decreasing, thus on this interval, the slope of the composite function is also strictly decreasing.

Comment: Well yes you can't assume what you want to prove already while solving.

Comment: Where did I do so ?

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is $$f'(x)=\frac{2(1-\cos(x))-x \sin(x)}{(1-\cos(x))^2}=\frac{4\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}-2x\cos \frac{x}{2} \sin \frac{x}{2}}{(1-\cos(x))^2}=\frac{2\sin \frac{x}{2}(2\sin \frac{x}{2}-x \cos \frac{x}{2})}{(1-\cos(x))^2}$$

All terms here are non-negative on $(0,2\pi)$, except possibly $2 \sin \frac{x}{2}-x \cos \frac{x}{2}$. We will prove that it is nonnegative as well. i.e. $$2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \geq x \cos \frac{x}{2}$$
For $x \in[\pi,2\pi)$ is it obvious, because the RHS is non-positive, white the LHS is non-negative.

For $x \in (0,\pi)$, divide by the cosine, to get $2 \tan \frac{x}{2}-x\geq0$, which follows from the identity $\tan t \geq t$ for $t \in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

In summary, we proved $f' \geq 0$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to differentiate (though , I'll suggest differentiating . It would be easy to prove).

You can draw the curve for this function.

[image]

You can see that function increases monotonically in $[0,2\pi]$.(Aproaching to $\infty$ at $x=2\pi$)

Else. $$f'(x)=\dfrac{2(1-\cos x)-x\sin x}{(1-\cos x)^2}$$

Numerator(N) is 0 at x=0. And now differentiate the numerator.

You get N'=$\sin x- x \cos x$.Now as tanx > x . So, $N'\ge 0$ .and thus N increases as x increases.

ie.N +ve . And also denominator(D) is a perfect square, so it is positive.So $f'\ge0$

So the function increases in $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Why is it positive? Also, the numerator is rather $(1-\cos x)^2 -(x-\sin x)\sin x$.

Comment: This doesn't prove anything. Why could you say "$f'(x)$ is positive" by just looking at it?

Comment: Ok, the numerator is ok, if we expand it..

Comment: @Berci I think you need to expand your expression .And if it is so, i'll add how it is +ve.

Comment: Please add. I also started this way, and couldn't see why it should be positive.

Comment: Are you serious @Lipschitz . You don't want to differentiate either and can't even draw curves? I'm afraid you'll get a even different answer.

Comment: We don't have $\tan x\ge x$ in the whole $[0,2\pi]$ interval.. but starting to convince...

Comment: For rest of the period it's like we can directly see $f'>0$ as $\sin x<0$